# Division by zero occurred when doing combinations

Tags: c++, error-handling, combinations

I'm trying to compute math combinations. The formula I'm using is `N! / K! (N-K)!`.

I am able to get the right answer (`10`) with `N=5`, `K=2`, and `120` from `N=10`, `K=3`.

BUT when I tried to test with bigger number like `N=50`, `K=5.` The integer division by zero error popped out.

I tried to define `finalAns` with `long int` but it does not work as well. Any ideas?

```
int N;
int init;
int K;
int factN = 1;
int factK = 1;
double finalAns;

cout << "Input of N = ";
cin >> N;
cout << "Input of K = ";
cin >> K;

int subs = N - K;
int factsubs = 1;

for (init = 1; init <= N; init++)
{

    factN = factN * init;
}
for (init = 1; init <= K; init++)
{

    factK = factK * init;
}
cout << "K is " << factK << endl;
for (init = 1; init <= subs; init++)
{

    factsubs = factsubs * init;
}

finalAns = factN / (factK * factsubs);
cout << N << "C" << K << " is " << finalAns << endl;
```

Comment: Integer overflow? Have you tried using e.g. `long`? Or `long long`? Or the `unsigned variants`? And please learn how to use a debugger and step through the code line by line to see what's happening, while monitoring the variables and their values.

Comment: Also, since the division you make is an integer division, assigning it to a floating-point variable doesn't matter, you won't get any decimals anyway.

Comment: `subs` is being set to `45` in this case. `factsubs` is 1. when you try to multiply it with `init` in a loop which eventually increments to `45` causes integer overflow for `factsubs`, its value goes to minus numbers and eventually after some multiplication it is set to `0`. Now `init * 0 = 0`. You may use `long long` for `finalAnswer` and `factsubs` that may work on it. Remember if it works, the problem will regenerate with higher values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the multiply-at-one-go approach.

- Don't calculate `N!` at one go.
- Use the fact that division of any two positive integers reduces the end result, so favor division to have the lower intermediate values.

**Expand** the expression of `N!/(N-K)! * K!` to accommodate as much of division operation in ***intermediate*** steps as possible to lessen the chance of overflow.

Do not go for calculation of `N!` or `(N-K)!` or `K!` separately, you are more likely to face the overflow problem. Instead use the fact that *eventually* you need to divide the big numbers, why not do it **before** it becomes **BIG**!

More hints:

```
N!/(N-K)! = multiply i[N..N-K+1] one by one //not i[N..1]
```

and, check if any factor(`f`) of value `j from [2..K]` perfectly divides the intermediate-product-value(`p`), if yes, do the division : `p = p/f` and `j = j/f`.

Answer (score 0):

10! is very big: 3.628.800 - if this one is big, just imagine 50!

Depending on what compiler you are using, you might handle preety good 15! using long long. However that is not big enough - so you need to do something else... You can make an algorithm for multiplication that returns a character array - there is no way to return a long int or something else like that.

Comment: The size of an `int` (or any other type) doesn't depend on the compiler. It depends on the architecture.